Receiving BulkIndexError mapper_parsing_exception when trying to vectorize documents using langchain_community's OpenSearchVectorSearch
I am trying to vectorize documents to an OpenSearch database using the following Python code:
from langchain_core.documents import Document
from langchain_community.embeddings import HuggingFaceEmbeddings
from langchain_community.vectorstores import OpenSearchVectorSearch


local_url = "http://username:password@localhost:9200"
remote_url = "https://username:passord@remotehost:443"

index = "sample_dummy"
text = "This is a sample sentence."
metadata = {"doc_id": "1"}
docs = [Document(page_content=text, metadata=metadata)]
embeddings = HuggingFaceEmbeddings()
OpenSearchVectorSearch.from_documents(
    docs,
    embeddings,
    opensearch_url=remote_url,
    engine="faiss",
    space_type="innerproduct",
    ef_construction=64,
    m=24,
    bulk_size=1,
    index_name=index
)

This works as expected when vectorizing to a locally-hosted OpenSearch database. However, when attempting to vectorize to an AWS OpenSearch serverless instance, I receive the following error:
BulkIndexError: ('1 document(s) failed to index.', [{'index': {'_index': 'sample_dummy', '_id': 'c45a6a8b-d521-416c-acc0-33a65b54c096', 'status': 400, 'error': {'type': 'mapper_parsing_exception', 'reason': "failed to parse field [vector_field] of type [knn_vector] in document with id 'c45a6a8b-d521-416c-acc0-33a65b54c096'. Preview of field's value: '[0.03186225891113281, -0.08652590960264206, -0.019854316487908363, -0.018041256815195084, -0.08103588223457336, 0.01659131422638893, -0.015199257992208004, 0.009178114123642445, -0.03798457235097885, -0.017357641831040382, 0.08603041619062424, 0.013450289145112038, 0.01691741868853569...

After simplifying my real code to the snippet above, I tried adjusting the locally hosted instance to use the https protocol in hopes of matching the error consistently occurring on the remote instance. However, this did not affect the results.
What might be causing this error?
